# aws ecs run ecs task with container overrides

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-ecs

Looking for help on a java app to run ECS scheduled task! the program works fine and invokes the task without the overrides.  when we pass overrides it gives an error. is there some issue?

```
   ListTaskDefinitionFamiliesRequest request = new ListTaskDefinitionFamiliesRequest();
        ListTaskDefinitionFamiliesResult response = client.listTaskDefinitionFamilies(request);
        List<String> ls = response.getFamilies();
            String cmd[] ={"arg1","arg2"};
            List<String> command = Arrays.asList(cmd);
            TaskOverride overrides = new TaskOverride();
            ContainerOverride containerOverrides = new ContainerOverride();
            containerOverrides.setCommand(command);
            overrides.withContainerOverrides(containerOverrides);
            String subnets[] ={"subnet-bbb","subnet-ccc"};
            List<String> subnetList = Arrays.asList(subnets);
            String securityGrp[] ={"sg-xxx"};
            List<String> securityGrpList = Arrays.asList(securityGrp    );
            AwsVpcConfiguration awsvpcConfiguration = new AwsVpcConfiguration();
            awsvpcConfiguration.setSubnets(subnetList);
            awsvpcConfiguration.setSecurityGroups(securityGrpList);
            NetworkConfiguration networkConfiguration = new NetworkConfiguration();
            networkConfiguration.setAwsvpcConfiguration(awsvpcConfiguration);
        RunTaskRequest request = new RunTaskRequest()
                .withCluster("cluster-ecs")
                .withTaskDefinition("task:1")
                .withCount(1)
                .withLaunchType("FARGATE")              
                .withNetworkConfiguration(networkConfiguration);
                .withOverrides(overrides);
        RunTaskResult response = client.runTask(request);
```

Comment: `when we pass overrides it gives error` please show us the error

Comment: Unknown options: command:

Comment: errors are not user friendly.  got the underlying error after reading through the apis few times.

Answer (score 1):

container name is required field in overrides. all set now.

```
            containerOverrides.setName("blabla");
        containerOverrides.setCommand(command);
```